# How to get the browser name alone from client in java?

Tags: java

I tried using

```
 String userAgent=req.getHeader("user-agent");
```

and also the following

```
@GET
    @Path("/get")
    public Response addUser(@HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) {

        return Response.status(200)
            .entity("addUser is called, userAgent : " + userAgent)
            .build();

    }
```

But I need only, browser name as chrome,firefox,IE.Please help,if anyone know.

**UPDATE** : Got answer

```
 public String browser(@HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent){

        UserAgent browserName = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgent);
        String browser=browserName.toString();
        System.out.println(browser)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting information out of user agent strings is somewhat of a black art. Easiest is probably to use a library to parse the user agent string and extract the needed information.

I've used [UADetector](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/) in the past with good results, but there are undoubtedly other libraries out there.

The following sample is from the UADetector [documentation](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/usage.html#usage_in_a_servlet):

```
UserAgentStringParser parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();
ReadableUserAgent agent = parser.parse(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));

out.append("You're a <em>");
out.append(agent.getName());
out.append("</em> on <em>");
out.append(agent.getOperatingSystem().getName());
out.append("</em>!");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply,I am very new to this.I am working in dropwizard,when I call a path,it should find the browser name and use it in web driver..as whether to use chrome or firefox driver ,in java class.Can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: One question at the time. The current question has been answered, and now it's up to you to either accept the answer, or wait for a better one. If you have another question, create a new question, provide the necessary context, and take it from there.